# Is this ordered set of vectors a dcpo?

Tags: vector-spaces, order-theory

The definition of a dcpo, or directed complete partial order, [can be found here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_partial_order).

A real vector is formed with a basis set $B =\{ e_1, e_2 \ldots \}$, and the real numbers $\mathbb{R}$.  A vector is a formal sum of the form $v = \Sigma_i a_i e_i$, for $a_i \in \mathbb{R}$.  Let us define the "terms" as a span $\mathbb{R} \leftarrow Term \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.  Where the left arrow gives the real coefficient and the right arrow gives an integer, identifying the basis vector.  This allows us to have a set of "terms", binding the basis vector to the coefficient.  Two vectors may have some of the same terms.  We can even say that, for $v,w$, $Term_v \subseteq Term_w$ which means that $w$ has all the terms of $v$ and perhaps some more (or no more)

Define the following ordering:

$v \le w$ if $Term_v \subseteq Term_w$

Does this define a dcpo?  What kind of ordering is this?  What are the compact elements of the dcpo?

Comment: directed-complete partial order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's something weird: can you have vectors with an infinite number of non-trivial coordinates (since you wrote "formal sum") in your set (let's call it $$)?

- I assume it's not the case (as you tagged your question under "vector spaces"): in this case, your set is *not* a dcpo if your basis set is infinite: consider the set $$\left\{ \sum_{i≤n} e_i \mid n ∈ ℕ\right\}$$ it's a chain (hence a directed set), but it has no upper bound.
- if your basis set is finite (let's denote by $n ∈ ℕ$ its cardinal), you can write every vector $v ≝ \sum\limits_{i=0}^n a_i e_i$ as the $n$-tuple $(a_i, \ldots, a_n) ∈ ℝ^n$. As it happens, since $$v ≝ \sum\limits_{i=0}^n a_i e_i ≤ w ≝ \sum\limits_{i=0}^n a_i' e_i \quad ⟺ \quad ∀i, \, a_i = 0 \, ∨ \; a_i = a_i'$$ your set $$ is a product of flat pointed dcpos (where $0 ≤ a$ for every $a ≠ 0$ and $a ≤ a$ for every $a$ (and you have no other order relations)), and, as such, is a dcpo (the category of dcpos is cartesian closed).

  As for the compact elements in this case: one can show that every directed set is finite (of cardinal at most $n$), and thus contains its least upper bound. As a consequence, all non-zero vectors are compact.

Comment: Hi, thanks very much for answering.  I will mark this as the answer in a minute.  Please keep an eye out for my next question because I am going to use your result to ask a question I have been looking to answer for a while.

Comment: Hi, I am trying to give a proof of the following: the closed form functions from R to R are compact in a dcpo of functions.  I wanted to use this question as the proof by talking about functions as vectors over a basis of functions.  If the basis has to be finite, then it doesn't quite work.  Do you have a suggestion on how to get a little closer to a proof?

Comment: @BenSprott You're welcome! What do you mean by "closed form functions"?

Comment: I mean, given a basis of functions or several bases, a closed form function is anything that can be written in a finite expression in the basis, a finite formal sum of basis functions.

Comment: I have posted my question here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/307688/the-closed-form-real-valued-functions-are-compact-in-a-dcpo-of-functions